# Why does my MATLAB code duplicate all symbols except spaces, which it removes?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

My goal is to take an encrypted string and duplicate all symbols.  Because the only inputs will be lowercase, I ignored taking uppercase characters into account.

I designed my code to anticipate the total length of the end result with duplicated symbols, which is why I add `punct`, a variable that contains the total number of symbols in the string, to the length of the string.  When iterating, if the code comes across a symbol, it should save the subsequent part of the encrypted string as `sub`, and duplicate the symbol it came across in the next index.  Finally, the encrypted string from index 1 to that of the duplicated symbol is concatenated with the saved substring, which I have tested to work in all cases of symbols, between type and number.  My one issue is that this will not function with spaces, which it deletes instead of duplicating.  I went through the code stepwise and think it may be due to the `strcat` function.  This leaves me confused because spaces should be treated like any other ASCII character.  When I get an error, it says it is due to array out of bounds.

The test case I used was `encrypted = hlnv.ylwb.lmxv.glow.nv` and `hlnv ylwb lmxv glow nv`.  In both `punct` is 4 because there are 4 non-letter characters in each.

```
criticallength = length(encrypted) + punct;
ii = 1;
while ii <= criticallength
    if encrypted(ii) < 97 || encrypted(ii) > 122
        sub = encrypted(ii + 1:end);
        encrypted(ii + 1) = encrypted(ii);
        encrypted = strcat(encrypted(1:ii + 1), sub);
        ii = ii + 1;
    end
    ii = ii + 1;
end
```

Comment: Please include a definition of `encrypted` and `punct`, so that we may run your code and see it working. In particular, there is a difference between strings and char arrays in MATLAB that would be very relevant here.

Comment: “The test case I used was `encrypted = hlnv.ylwb.lmxv.glow.nv`” This leaves out the critical bit of information I was asking about. Note how that is not valid MATLAB syntax. It is either `e='str'` or `e="str"`, the two cases would cause wildly different behavior in MATLAB. Please be specific, post a code block that is self-contained and complete, so we can copy-paste it. That is the best way to avoid imprecision. See [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `strcat` removes trailing white spaces, according to [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

> For character array inputs, strcat removes trailing ASCII white-space
> characters: space, tab, vertical tab, newline, carriage return, and
> form feed. For cell and string array inputs, strcat does not remove
> trailing white space.

That means `strcat('A ', 'B')` results `'AB'`, while `strcat('A', ' B')` results `'A B'`. But in your case, you do not need to call `strcat`. Instead, you can simply use array concatenation, like `['A ' 'B']` that returns your desired output, `'A B'`.